# a measurable function on R

Tags: measure-theory

Please, can you give me a suggestion?
We have $(A_{n})_{n\ge 1} $ a sequence of  measurable Lebesgue sets, disjoint two by two ($A_{n}\cap A_{m}$ is empty, for $m \neq n$ and $(a_{n})_{n\ge 1}$ a sequence of real numbers. I have to prove that the function:$$f=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_{n}\chi_{A_{n}}$$ is measurable on R, the set of real numbers. We have that $\chi_{A_{n}}$ is measurable, if $A_{n}$ is measurable; then, $a_{n}\chi_{A_{n}}$ is measurable. Would this idea of mine help?

Comment: Yeah, it's a good start. Now use that a) the sum of two measurable functions is measurable and b) the pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very helpful idea! The other fact you should combine that with is that if $f$ and $g$ are measurable and $fg=0$ then $f+g$ is measurable. Combining this with your analysis yields the answer.

Comment: Thank you both, I get it!!

Comment: Sorry, Stella, I did it now!